# Filtering Angular-ui Scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, virtualscroll, ui-scroll

I am trying to implement infinity type scrolling on a simple grid. Html is like this:

```
<div class="text-center" style="background-color:#eee;">
    <H2 style="margin-top:0px;">Customer List</H2>
    <hr />
    Search: <input ng-model="customerVm.search" /> <br /> <br />

    <table class="table table-hover" ui-scroll-viewport style="height:500px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr ui-scroll="customer in customerVm.datasource" ng-model="customerVm.gridResult" "buffer-size="10">
                <td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to filter what is in the grid based on the search box model, seems simple enough. I would normally just use the following with an ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat="customer in customerVm.datasource | filter:customerVm.search" ng-model="customerVm.gridResult" "buffer-size="10">
                <td>{{customer.customername}}</td>
            </tr>
```

However with the use of "ui-scroll" instead of ng-repeat I am getting an error

```
Expected uiScroll in form of '_item_ in _datasource_' but got 'customer in customerVm.datasource | filter:customerVm.search'
```

Am I missing something on how to filter the data using  Angular-ui scroll? I see the line in the scroll lib that is causing the issue which throws an error if there is anything other then

```
item in datasource
```

This makes me think that filtering is not possible in Angular-ui scroll. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 2):

Filtering is unfortunately not yet possible in this way, as the error suggests. See "Parameters" in the [Readme file](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll#parameters). You could implement your own filter in the data source "get" function. See also the official [examples](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-scroll/demo/).